# Undefined index in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

Here is my simple form:

```
<form action = "input" method = "POST">
Name: <input type="text" name="uname"/> <br>
<input type="submit" name="button" value="hit it" >
</form>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function indexaction()
{
    $db= new DataBase();
    $db->initDB("testform", "benjaminsform");
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","benjaminsform");
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
        if(isset($_POST["button"])) {
            $uname=$_POST['uname'];
        }
        $success=$db->insert(array("name"=>$uname));
    }

    return array();
}
```

And this is the error im receiving"

> Notice: Undefined variable: uname in /usr/local/zend/var/apps/http/v-hrswebapps/80/benjamintestapp/1.0.0_201/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/IndexController.php on line 27
>
> Line 27 the one in question is the $success statement.

Ive tried working with my isset statements but nothing is really passing into the array.

Comment: Zend framework is an application framework, this means that you should not check for the `$_SERVER` variables yourself, instead you rely to the frameworks form handling and validation classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to get the post data

```
public function indexaction()
{
   $request = $this->getRequest();
   if ($request->isPost()){
      $params = $request->getPost();
      $uname = $params['uname'];
   }
}
```

But it seems like your action is input but your code is under indexaction that's why it is not getting your postdata